# Why is my slab still warm 24-hours after turning of in-floor heating?

Tags: plumbing, water, leak, slab

Looks like we have a slab leak in our house.  I noticed warm tiles around the laundry area where we have pinpointed the hottest point and the warmth seems to spread about 6 feet outwards.

The weird thing is, the water in the house was shut off 24 hours ago, but the floor tiles are still warm. I cannot work out why.

Any ideas? 12 hours ago I also turned the pilot light off at the water heater, but tiles are still warm. How can this be? Surely after 24 hours it cant be residual heat?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: After 24 hours a slab could retain plenty of heat to still feel warm, especially if it’s a thick one. You shouldn’t jump to the conclusion that you have a leak just based on this. You should seek further proof if you are concerned.

Comment: Thanks Paul. We certainly have a slab leak as determined by a plumber. The issue is the heat retention 2 days after the water has been shut off. Was wondering if this was common as I wouldn't think water/concrete could stay hot so long.

Comment: Having the same issue. Haven’t confirmed a slab leak yet. Can you provide more details on your situation ? Was it confirmed slab leak ? How did you fix it ? How much did it cost ?

Comment: It was a slab leak. The warm floor is usually a solid giveaway and in our case, it was.
It was fixed by a plumber re-routing the water pipes through the roof/attic (where access is possible) as you can't dig up the house slab on the floor. Quit a common situation and done every day by plumbers so only took an afternoon.

Comment: Hm.
 I haven't seen pipes run under/through the slab (except perhaps for drains and, as noted, for jacketed oil lines where the jacket permits replacing the line), presumably for exactly this reason. But I'm in an area where basements are still by far the most common way to build a house, so burying things under concrete doesn't have much practical justification.

Comment: We are in Las Vegas - all homes are new builds so plumbing is always underground/in the slab.